# Ubuntu 18.04 Server - Install Loop

Tags: server, system-installation, 18.04

I am installing Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a Thinkstation S20 - it previously ran successfully with both 16.04 desktop and server.

When stepping through the installer as expected, I get to the step where it asks which drive to install on. After selecting the only drive in the system and pressing enter, it displays some logs very briefly (seems to be a python stack trace), then returns back to the first step of the installer. This loop repeats indefinitely.

Other miscellaneous information:

- The drive is a 64GB SSD
- The singular network interface is receiving a
  DHCP address in the 10.10.10.0/24 subnet
- RAM is a single 8GB stick

Any ideas?

Comment: For me the loop was from the point where you set up the network connection, but @MattGarrod's answer fixed that too.  Subiquity didn't see the Wifi device, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem this morning. It seems to be a problem with the new Subiquity installer. I have downloaded the alternative installer disc (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/) which uses the old installer and this has installed 18.04 Server without a problem

Comment: This appears to be the issue. The python stack trace I saw flash suggests a crash. I used a different boot disk and it worked well. Conclusion: Some disks crash the subuquity, leading to the symptom of a loop?

Comment: Coming back a few months later, this has happened several more times for me. It just seems to crash on some systems.

Comment: Happened to me also ONLY when i had no ethernet cable connected. I connected one, got ip and it worked. So the problem must be no internet when trying to get the mirror url for "Configure Ubuntu archive mirror"

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has eth, just connect it to internet via cable and the wizard will continue to the `Configure Ubuntu archive mirror` step`.